# Django: any use of blocktrans causes TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

Using Django 1.2.1, any use of blocktrans breaks my template. Eg

```
{%blocktrans%}text{%endblocktrans%}
```

Results in:

Django Version: 1.2.1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Invalid block tag: 'blocktrans'

Removing the blacktrans causes the code to work. Django s running on GAE if that's relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add that to your built-in tags like this, instead:

```
# in urls.py
template.add_to_builtins('django.templatetags.i18n')
```

Any tag I'm using in multiple templates, I just load into there.

Comment: Actually I think your answer's better than mine - less code. Making this one the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19):

Answering my own question, I'd forgotten:

```
{% load i18n %}
```

In the top of the template. This is required to use the blocktrans tag.

**Edit**: See orokusaki's improved answer below to fix this permanently for all your templates.